# CosmosDB Emulator Docker container not starting when enabling mongoDB endpoint

Tags: docker, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am following step-by-step instructions for a macOS on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/docker-emulator-linux?tabs=mongodb-api%2Cssl-netstd21. When I get to step 3 I can only manage to start the container for NoSQL API but when I try to start it for MongoDB the container won't start. This is what I have tried:

```
docker run \
--publish 8081:8081 \
--publish 10250-10255:10250-10255 \
--name=test-linux-emulator-mongo \
--env AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=10 \
--env AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=true \
--env AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=$ipaddr \
--env AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_MONGODB_ENDPOINT=4.2 \
--interactive \
--tty \
mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:latest
```

The above code is the only one that is not giving the expiration error but it does not assign a proper port and exits with code 0 straight away.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed with the [latest image](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-db-emulator-docker/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed), you should be able to get it up and running.

```
mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator:mongodb
```